# Language of a string table in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008

In Visual C++ 2008, in the "Resource View" panel, how to know the language of a string table, and how to change the language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to know the language of a string table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21813119/how-to-know-the-language-of-a-string-table)

Comment: @Blastfurnace: that has no answer...

Answer (score 3):

It is prominently displayed, you can't miss it:

[image]

Guessing at the real problem, you probably haven't yet figured out how to add another language.  It is fairly hard to find.  Right-click the original string table, like the one I highlighted in the screen-shot, a click "Insert Copy...".  You'll get a dialog that asks you to specify the language:

[image]